# Scheduled large file transfer with transfer time window

Tags: windows, file-transfer

I am looking for a way to copy a very large VHD file across a rather slow WAN. Ideally a mechanism where I can provide a window for the transfer, say 8PM to 5AM, and the transfer will pause during business hours and then pick back up again after hours the next day. Ideally something Windows native not a separate purchase, as this is a one time need. Does such a beast exist, or am I searching for a unicorn?

Comment: Is sneakernet not viable? i.e. a usb drive and car/walk/post.

Comment: @cjb110, WAN, not LAN. Sneakernet from London to Edinburgh is not particularly efficient. ;) If it was a one time thing, maybe, but we need to do some extensive VM testing, and the outsourced IT can't seem to handle a VM host in each location, so cloned VHDs need to travel.

Comment: ugh:(  Any coders available as you could possibly write something in .Net or PowerShell to utilize BITS, rather than scheduled its QoS based, so shouldn't interfere with other traffic: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/bits/background-intelligent-transfer-service-portal

Comment: I am a coder, so I will likely do my own BITS implementation, but often I have rolled my own only to find PowerShell has something native, so I thought better to ask first, code later. ;)

Comment: I know you can initate a bits download with powershell: `Import-Module BitsTransfer;
Start-BitsTransfer -Source $url -Destination $output`  Not sure if there is enough options on there for you?

Answer (score -1):

Not native but free.
Free Download Manager (the Old Version 3.9.7)
Can create schedules (Called Time Limit) as well as bandwidth throttle so WAN link isn't saturated etc. 
Also supports resume if you allow it on FTP Server.
You would need to have FTP server serving up the VHD.